# How to get a user's friend list from graph api without authentication?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can see a user's friend list in facebook.com but I can't get this by graph api. I use this fql in "Graph API Explorer" :

```
SELECT uid1 FROM friend WHERE uid2=100002756991450
```

but it tell me:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Error validating access token: Session has expired at unix time 1358668800. The current unix time is 1358677687.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 190,
    "error_subcode": 463
  }
}
```

How can I get a user's friend list without authentication?

Comment: _“How can I get a user's friend list without authentication?”_ – not at all, of course.

Comment: but i can see friend list in facebook.com.

Comment: Congratulations. Not relevant, however. What you can do as a user on facebook.com and what you can do via API are to different sets of things.

Comment: thanks! this is the question : "is any action in facebook.com can perform by API?". I was thinking it is!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Not due to authentication, this is because user's session has been expired, So generate new access token and use it.
You could get this error.
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Can't lookup all friends of 515977793 due to user's privacy settings.", 
    "type": "NoIndexFunctionException", 
    "code": 604
  }
}

if user has a privacy.